# Como fazer serialize com input disable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em uma resposta no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748655/how-to-make-serialize-take-into-account-those-disabled-input-elements)

Eles passam uma abordagem de desabilitar temporariamente os campos:

**Exemplo:**

```
var myform = $('#myform');

 // Encontra os elementos e remove o atributo disable
var disabled = myform.find(':input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');

 // serialize o form
var serialized = myform.serialize();

 // coloca todos os elementos que foram desabilidados disable
disabled.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Existe alguma forma mais eficiente de fazer `serialize()` em campos de formulário que estão desabilitados ?

Comment: Não me parece, creio que terás sempre de remover o atributo 'disabled'.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem 2 votos de fechamento como fora do escopo por não ser um problema de programação. Quem votou pelo fechamento, gostaria de justificar? Pois para mim parece ser uma pergunta perfeitamente dentro do escopo. Ela está na fila de análise de fechamento, e como não vejo nada de errado vou clicar no botão "Deixar aberta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia resolver este problema percorrendo os elementos `disabled` para pegar o `name e o value` e no final concatenando com a string serializada para enviar ao servidor.

**Exemplo:**

```
function getDisableInput(form) {
   var input = $("#" + form + " input:disabled");
   var result = '';
   $.each(input, function (key, val) {
      result += "&" + val.name + '=' + val.value;
   });
   return result;
}

var disableInput = getDisableInput('form');  
var dados = $("#form").serialize() + disableInput; // agora é só enviar para o servidor.
```

Outra forma interessante de conseguir o mesmo resultado é percorrendo todos os campos do seletor `'input[type=text]'` assim nem será necessario utilizar o serialize para os input's do type text.

**Exemplo 2:**

```
var dados = '';

$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
  dados += '&' + this.id + '=' + this.value;
});

console.log(dados);
```

Comment: Leia estes comentários [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849693/what-is-the-best-way-to-submit-disabled-inputs-as-part-of-a-jquery-ajax-request).

Comment: @Edilson é requisito estar disabled e não readyonly, a resposta do 
"tvanfosson" é feita da mesma forma que a minha.  o que difere é que a minha apresenta um pouco mais de desempenho por uso de seletores id's e não utizar attr sendo que eles poderiam ser acessados por .atributo diretamente.

Comment: Os comentários referentes ao '&' não aos selectores, além de estar limitado ao tipo `text`.

Comment: @Edilson seria aquele do  gruszczy dizendo que deveria antes verificar se o form esta vazio para  não enviar & sozinho ?