# Como aplicar readonly em um select?

Tags: html, css, html5, html-select

Creio que a maioria aqui conhece a [diferença entre **`readonly`** e **`disabled`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6773/14213).

#### Select Readonly

O `readonly` não se aplica corretamente para o `select`

```html
<select name="field" readonly="readonly">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Cliente</option>
  <option value="2">Contador</option>
  <option value="3">Vendedor</option>
</select>
```

Como podem ver eu ainda consigo alterar o valor do `select`

#### Select Disabled

O que não ocorre com o `disabled` que de fato bloqueia o select

```html
<select name="field" disabled="disabled">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" selected>Cliente</option>
  <option value="2">Contador</option>
  <option value="3">Vendedor</option>
</select>
```

Aqui eu não consigo editar, mas ele também são é enviado pelo formulário.

#### Objetivo

Eu necessito enviar o conteúdo do select pelo formulário, mas o usuário não pode editá-lo, seu conteúdo é auto selecionado por outros fatores.

#### Duvida

- Como bloquear o `select`, mas ainda enviar seu valor pelo `form`?
- Seria possível sem uso de js?

#### Adendo

Desta forma eu tenho o que quero, mas gostaria de um método mais elegante, aqui ele ainda consegue ver as opções.

```html
<select name="field">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled"></option>
  <option value="1" disabled="disabled" selected>Cliente</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Contador</option>
  <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Vendedor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ele não envia nenhum valor quando o campo tá desabilitado? Você envia esses dados por Ajax?

Comment: @Laerte exatamente ele sequer envia o `name` do select, é como se nem existi-se. Aqui eu uso ajax, mas não pretendia pegar o conteúdo por js, ou `jquery.param`

Comment: Se vc utilizar jquery: vc deixa o campo select habilitado envia o valor do form c/ selected e só depois usa o jquery para desabilitar o campo. utilizando o $( document ).ready( ... )

Comment: Não seria mais simples mostrar um input text normal nesse caso? Usualmente eu só ponho select quando a pessoa pode mudar os dados. Se é readonly desde o server, o trabalho de mudar um "readonly" ou o tipo de input é o mesmo. Se for usar JS, é o caso de só mudar o tipo do input dinamicamente também.

Comment: Concordo com o @Bacco, se o utilizador não pode alterar nem visualizar as outras opcções qual é a necessidade de utilizar um select? Se pretende mostrar que este campo futuramente poderá vir a ser editado acho que disabled seria a melhor opção.  Basicamente neste momento você está a enganar o utilizador, pois irá parecer uma combo box que não está a funcionar correctamente.

Comment: @lazyFox uma opção até mais elegante que a resposta mais votada atualmente (que eu discordo que seja uma solução real) é por apenas um option com o valor desejado nos casos "readonly" kkkkkkkk

Comment: Exactamente, nem mais XD

Comment: @Bacco que eu me lembre (ja faz muito tempo), desejava fazer isso para um formulário, de cadastro, que era utilizado tbm para editar, contudo na criação o select era liberado, mas no edit não.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert creio que um JS trocando o tipo de input ao entrar no modo de edição ainda seja mais simpático do que tentar "tampar" o acesso ao campo como proposto em algumas respostas.

Comment: @Bacco Não descordo, mas ai já começamos a entrar em gostos pessoais, ai vai de cada um. O bom é ter opções :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert o que me preocupa é funcionar sem efeitos colaterais, nem acho que seja gosto. Mas acho que vc já pegou a idéia, qq coisa depois detalhamos melhor no chat pra não alongar demais aqui ;) - Alguém dos usuários mais confiáveis do site deu uma idéia legal também (por outros meios), teriamos que testar a validade: colocar disabled em todas as opçõs do select (menos a desejada) para simular o readonly.

Comment: Se voce não vai usar o select para edição, exiba o conteúdo num input text.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Pode desabilitar os eventos do mouse, teclado e touch do select usando apenas `css`, assim o campo terá apenas a aparência e comportamento de desabilitado, porém ele continuará habilitado.

- `pointer-events: none` - Desabilita os eventos APENAS do mouse no elemento, qualquer ação tomada com o mouse sobre o elemento não terá qualquer efeito.
- `touch-action: none` - Desabilita as ações do touch em aparelhos mobile, note que essa é uma tecnologia experimental e com pouca compatibilidade ainda.
- `tabindex="-1"` - Como comentado pelo @CaioFelipePereira, o valor do `input` ainda pode ser alterado com o teclado. Usando o o `tabindex` negativo, o campo não estará acessível pelo `tab`, mas se for atribuído o `focus` ao `input` de outra maneira o valor poderá ser alterado.
- `aria-disabled="true"` - Por questões de acessibilidade, informe para leitores de tela que seu campo está desabilidado.

```css
select[readonly] {
  background: #eee; /*Simular campo inativo - Sugestão @GabrielRodrigues*/
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<select readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" selected>Cliente</option>
  <option value="2">Contador</option>
  <option value="3">Vendedor</option>
</select>
```

Compatibilidade - pointer-events

- Chrome: 2.0
- Firefox (Gecko): 3.6 (1.9.2)
- Internet Explorer: 11.0
- Opera: 15.0
- Safari (WebKit): 4.0 (530)

Compatibilidade - touch-action

- Chrome Mobile: Sim
- IE Mobile: Sim

Fonte: [CSS Pointer Events - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) - [CSS Touch action - MDN (Em inglês)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action)

Comment: Depois é só adicionar o id especifico porque dessa forma qualquer select irá ficar "desabilitado". +1

Comment: O mais interessante é não depender de javascript +1

Comment: Simples porém funcional, não sabia desse modo ;) +1

Comment: Isso que eu chamo de "solução elegante" :D +1

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior Perfeitamente. Não consigo edita-lo e envia normalmente.

Comment: Talvez seja interessante incluir uma observação que esta propriedade não funciona no Internet Explorer e o usuário pode alterar normalmente o valor do select.

Comment: Editado @renan. Obrigado! GuilhermeLautert da uma olhada na edição que fiz, adicionei uma nova propriedade que é usada para mobile/touch.

Comment: Assim fica legal também: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/7tg8t4v5/

Comment: Vale lembrar que isso não impede o usuário de usar o teclado pra alterar o valor do select. ;)

Comment: Verdade @CaioFelipePereira. Não tinha visto isso, é possível selecionar o campo utilizando `tab`. Já dei uma pesquisada, acho que podemos resolver esse problema usando o `tabindex="-1"`, dessa forma, não será acessível pelo `tab`, mas será que existe outra maneira de acessá-lo?

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior sem mouse e teclado habilitados, eu acho que não. Eu acho.

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1

Comment: +1 Boa resposta, mais ainda não percebi a utilidade desta pergunta XD

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente está não é uma solução exata para seu problema, é apenas uma forma que você pode usar, uma forma alternativa por assim dizer.

**Ok, mas por que?** Simplesmente por que é uma "gambiarra" e utiliza o elemento `disabled`.

Basicamente o que o código abaixo faz é esconder um campo `input` que vai ter o mesmo valor e o mesmo nome do `select`.

Chega de papo, aqui vai a demo.

```js
$('#mainform').submit(function() {
  $('#formdata_container').show();
  $('#formdata').html($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});

$('#enableselect').click(function() {
  $('#mainform input[name=opcao]')
    .attr("disabled", true);

  $('#op-select')
    .attr('disabled', false)
    .attr('name', 'opcao');

  $('#enableselect').hide();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#formdata_container {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="mainform">
    <select id="op-select" disabled="true">
      <option value="op1" selected>Opção 1</option>
      <option value="op2">Opção 2</option>
      <option value="op3">Opção 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="opcao" value="1" />

    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="formdata_container" style="display:none">
  <div>Dado enviado:</div>
  <div id="formdata">
  </div>
</div>
```

Você pode ver no `.js` tem a linha do `#enableselect`, ela é caso você queira, poderá colocar uma opção para ativar a escolha do usuário.

Para adicionar o botão de ativar a escolha basta adicionar `<button id="enableselect">Enable</button>` abaixo do select.

Vi o código lá no [Stack em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input).

Outra opção é utilizando `javascript` puro. É a menos recomendada e só deve ser utilizada em última e emergencial estância porque ela trabalha no client-side e pode ser contornada utilizando a função [inspecionar elemento](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) do navegador (se bem que né...) além de parecer um bug para o usuário.

Para ver em funcionamento é só [clicar aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/v9L6utsq/) e ver a demo no jsfiddle.

Comment: é uma solução nada "elegante", mas responde o primeiro tópico. +1

Comment: concordo totalmente com a parte do "nada elegante" haha

Comment: Essa ai é a gambis que uso, até tinha criado uma pergunta pra isso, basicamente funciona com qualquer componente desabilitado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99435/como-fazer-serialize-com-input-disable

Comment: Passei a utilizar depois de descobri-la no SO, é bem útil e de verdade, prefiro usar essa do que outro modo pelo simples motivo da usabilidade, acredito que seja uma maneira mais limpa (no client-side) já que claramente você percebe que o input ta desabilitado, alguns outros modos não mostram o que pode parecer um "bug" como citado na resposta

Comment: Solução deselegante e requer manobras desnecessárias, é apenas realizar a implementação com CSS como feito na resposta acima e não receber os valores e não passar para o banco ou onde quer que vai guardar os dados.

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra forma de evitar que se altere o valor do `select` (sem usar CSS) é colocar um `onchange` com o valor do `selected`. Não impede de abrir o *dropdown*, mas impede que o valor seja alterado:

```html
<select name="field" onchange="this.value = '2'">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">Cliente</option>
   <option selected value="2">Contador</option>
   <option value="3">Vendedor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: este é o exemplo do programar inteligente contra o programar somente. top!

Answer (score 0):

por mim eu desativaria de verdade o select, com a diferença de que... o valor seria mandado para um input hidden, e ao clicar no submit do form ele enviasse o valor do input hidden, o único problema com esta abordagem, ou melhor, com o da pergunta em geral é se, o usuário se arrepender da escolha e decidir mudar, ai ele teria que recarregar a página de novo, perdendo os dados que já preencheu nos outros campos. neste caso você teria que adicionar um botão de 'editar' ao lado do select:
https://jsfiddle.net/fjzf15xa/

```js
$('#example').on('change', function() {
var selectVal = $(this).val();
  
  $(this).attr({
'disabled': true,
'aria-disabled': true
  });
  $('#selectHidden').val(selectVal)
});
```

```css
*,
 *::after,
 *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

  .container {
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
 }

.form__group {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
  .form__input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
 }

.button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
  .button--primary {
background-color: #19B5FE;
color: #fff; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" class="form">
<div class="form__group">
  <input type="text" class="form__input" value="Jhon Doe">
</div>
<div class="form__group">
  <select name="mydata" id="example" class="form__input">
    <option value="value1">value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">value 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="selectHidden">
</div>
<button class="button button--primary">enviar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```