# ReadOnly não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao incluir um item dinamicamente na `table`, eu quero deixar o campo `cbempresa` com o `readonly=true` e quando não tiver nenhum item na `table` ele precisa estar `readonly=false` , a lógica funciona quando utilizo `disabled`, mas `readonly` não.
Segue como estou fazendo:

```
$("#cbempresa").prop("readonly", true);
```

E aqui é para retirar o `readonly`:

```
  $("#cbempresa").prop("readonly", false)
```

Achei que era algo que eu estava fazendo errado, porém ao colocar `disabled` funciona.

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Talvez o contexto esteja impedindo alguma coisa.

Comment: Mariana, poderia informar na sua pergunta como é feita a inclusão de um novo item (É a inclusão de uma nova linha na tabela?, como ela é feita?) e se possível também nos diga que elemento do html é o"cbempresa" pois existem elementos que não são compatíveis com o `readonly` como por exemplo o `<select>`

Comment: @Sam isso acontece, quando estou adicionando dados dinamicamente na `table`, pensei que poderia ser algo que estava impedindo, mas pq ele impediria o readonly e não impediria o disabled?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero o input é `select` então não funciona `readonly` ?

Comment: O elemento `<select>` não possui o atributo `readonly`, veja [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Attributes). E o atributo `readonly` não recebe um valor `true` ou `false`, se ele está presente, o elemento é somente leitura, se não está presente não é, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172968/8133067).

Comment: Acho que existe uma pergunta com esse cenário. Estou tentando encontrar aqui.

Comment: Dá uma olha aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273982/8063

Comment: @Sam mas nesse caso pode confundir o usuário, pq o valor vai estar de outro que ele selecionou, porém ele pode mudar, não é isso, ou entendi errado ?

Comment: Mariana, no exemplo que mostrei, o usuário pode abrir o select mas não consegue alterar a opção selecionada. Seria uma emulação de `readonly`, já que no `disabled` o usuário não consegue nem abrir o select.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, apenas para esclarecimento, select e input são elementos distintos. o Pedro já respondeu a sua pergunta e deixou excelentes referências para um melhor entendimento. Agora sobre como lidar com essa situação, se você realmente precisa utilizar um `select`  você pode simular um `readonly` ao remover as possíveis interações do usuário com o campo, segue o link com algumas sugestões: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128188/como-aplicar-readonly-em-um-select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O elemento `<select>` (como no caso do seu elemento `#cbempresa`) não possui o atributo `readonly`, veja aqui:

> [<select> HTML Element - Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Attributes)

E o atributo `readonly` não recebe um valor `true` ou `false`, se ele está presente, o elemento é somente leitura, se não está presente não é, veja aqui:

> [What is the difference between readonly=“true” & readonly=“readonly”? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172968/8133067)

Veja um exemplo abaixo, o campo `nascimento` **não é** somente leitura e o campo `idade` **é** somente leitura:

```html
<input type="text" id="nascimento" name="nascimento">
<input type="text" id="idade" name="idade" readonly>
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Conforme mencionado nos comentários (Sam e Caique Romero), existem algumas alternativas para simular o comportamento *readonly* em um elemento `<select>`, veja aqui:

> [Como aplicar readonly em um select? - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128188/86952)

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação, mas optei colocar como `disabled` e ao enviar o form, eu retiro o disable para pegar o campo. Obrigado.